# Excel as Datasource in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

How can I give Excel as datasource in SSRS report I am developing SSRS report in Visual Studio 2008, please help me in this, I have read various links but unable to get desired results.

Comment: Your question is a little vague to answer or even suggest possible actions.  You should add details of what you have, what you want and what you've tried so far to achieve your goals.

Answer (score 5):

In Visual studio - there is an option to create a datasource from  an ODBC connection.  From these dialogs you should be able to create a machine dsn to the excel file you require.

So......   from your report in visual studio, Click `Create new DataSource...`

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: While making ODBC connection , LoginID and Pwd is required. Do I need to enter my credentials or what? Please suggest

Comment: unlikely you need to enter your credentials if the connection string is correct.  did you try and create the connection string?  did you try to connect?  I've updated my answer with step by step pictures creating the datasource.

Comment: Thanks man , that helped me a lot, but now when I am selecting record from Sheet, for that I have write Select * from Sheet1, it throws error which is as follows:-  ERROR [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'DB'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'DB' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator. and Sheet 1 is there in the excel, Can you please help

Comment: Also when I am creating new Datasource as per you Screenshot3 I am not able to select System Data Source , so I selected User Data Source

Comment: You need to declare the range in your select statement and make sure your column names are in row1  eg:" 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:B10]'   More [info](http://beyondrelational.com/quiz/sqlserver/tsql/2011/questions/query-out-data-from-excel-to-64-bit-sql-server-table.aspx)